# How to avoid too many `h.concat` in decorater

Tags: ruby-on-rails, decorator, draper

I'm using a lot of `h.concat` in a Decorator class like this:

```
  def vote_box(size)
    h.content_tag(:div, class: "vote-box #{size}") do
      h.concat(h.link_to(h.up_vote_phrase_path) do
        h.concat h.content_tag(:span, '', class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top vote vote-up', :'aria-hidden' => true)
      end)
      h.concat h.content_tag(:div, '0', class: 'vote-count')
      h.concat h.content_tag(:span, '', class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom vote vote-down', :'aria-hidden' => true)
    end
  end
```

First of all, I feel it's too much of `h.concat`.
Secondly, I don't like paren `do ~ end` block.

Is there better way to write these codes?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your method doesn't rely on anything in the Decorator class.
Perhaps moving it to a helper would make sense? Then much of the `h` methods are accessed more easily.

```
def vote_box(size)
  content_tag(:div, class: "vote-box #{size}") do
    link_to(up_vote_phrase_path) do
      content_tag(:span, '', class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top vote vote-up', :'aria-hidden' => true)
    end +
    content_tag(:div, '0', class: 'vote-count') +
    content_tag(:span, '', class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom vote vote-down', :'aria-hidden' => true)
  end
end
```

Comment: ah, sorry. This is kind of a draft. I gonna add functionality of vote system, therefore I'm using Decorator.